# is it possible to add more type-c port?

Tags: hdmi, external-display, portable, usb-3.1-type-c

I bought a portable monitor(Viewsonic va1655). In the monitor's manual, there are two options to connect:
option 1: type-c to type-c(power and data cable). one cable is enough for both power and data for this option.
option 2: HDMI to mini-HDMI(data cable) and type-c to USB port/power adapter(power cable). two cables are needed for this option.
I have a lenovo thinkpad e14. It has one type-c port for charging the laptop. option 1 works for me but I cannot charge the laptop and cannot connect the type-c cable for the portable monitor at the same time. I wonder that is there any way to use my type-c port for both charging the laptop and getting the signal for my portable monitor?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. That’s because for a one-cable link to your display, the USB-C port has to support DisplayPort Alt Mode, not just the USB protocol. This is not something a simple mechanical adapter can do. Furthermore, power might be a concern, too.

There exists one device that I’m aware of that allows you to “add a USB-C port”, with Power Delivery and DisplayPort Alt Mode: The [Wacom Link Plus](https://estore.wacom.com/en-US/catalog/product/view/id/2623/s/wacom-link-plus-adapter-ack42819/). Another user has confirmed [here](https://superuser.com/a/1691675/219095) that it does in fact work. However, with this device, you need a separate USB-C power supply and you need to connect two cables (USB + HDMI) to your laptop. Not really an improvement in my opinion. Just use the two cable solution.