# I need a solution for a Laptop display port output to usb-c or mini hdmi input on a monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, usb-c

I have a standard display port 1.2 on my laptop and I need a cable that will output from this to either a mini-HDMI input or a usb-c input. Except all my efforts on search engines on amazon etc give me cables that are the other way around. Anyone know if there is a good solution that will allow me to display from my laptop display port on a 1440p portable monitor?

My thinking is dp to female hdmi adaptor and then an hdmi to mini hdmi cable in that direction. Is this possible and if so, where can I find such parts?

Answer (score 0):

Adapting DisplayPort to HDMI is often possible using a passive converter, because many DisplayPort outputs support DisplayPort Dual-Mode. Inexpensive adapters are ubiquitous. The other way (adapting HDMI output to a device expecting DisplayPort) is much rarer. You may be overthinking/confusing product descriptions.

A single DisplayPort to *USB-C with DisplayPort* adapter is known to me: The [Wacom Link Plus](https://estore.wacom.com/en-US/catalog/product/view/id/2623/s/wacom-link-plus-adapter-ack42819/). It is [confirmed to work](https://superuser.com/a/1691675/219095). It also is not cheap.

I recommend getting a DisplayPort (plug) to HDMI (port) adapter ([example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08989D7RZ)) and an HDMI to Mini-HDMI cable. Only if that does not work should you consider other options like an *active* DisplayPort to HDMI converter.

Comment: The descriptions of cables and adapters are often confusing, and I think occasionally wrong, such as referring to a laptop port as an input when it is clearly an output to a monitor. I have seen that. I am basically just trying to set up a portable monitor with my laptop but I need to get a display port output to a mini HDMI input. The cables I have searched for tend to be unidirectional and only support mini HDMI to HDMI, not the other way around which is what I want.

Comment: HDMI cables always work in both directions.